# MongoDB: get elements of array field with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following BasicDBObject object:

```
     {
          "name":"joe"

           "jobs":
                  [
                       {"adress" : "adress1"
                        "years": 2},
                       {"adress" : "adress2"
                       "years"  :3}

     }
```

I want to get the "jobs" field and enter the "adress" field and "years" field

I traying somethink like ....object.get("jobs") ....get "adress" and " years" fields.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Use BasicDBList to read the array inside the "jobs". Then iterate over the array to get each object.

```
BasicDBList jobsArr = (BasicDBList) object.get("jobs");
```